# Tiff to array - error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gis, gdal

Hello,                                                                           I have some problem with converting Tiff file to numpy array. 
I have a 16 bit signed raster file and I want to convert it to numpy array. 
I using to this gdal libarary.

```
import numpy
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open("C:/.../dem.tif")
dem = numpy.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
```

At first glance, everything converts well, but I compared the result obtained in python with result in GIS software and I got different results.

**Python result**

[image: Python result]

**Arcmap result**

[image: Arcmap result]

I found many value in numpy array that are below 91 and 278 (real min and max values), that should not exist.

Comment: What does the actual image look like in Python?  You can use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(dem)`.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL already returns a Numpy array, and wrapping it in `np.array` by default creates a copy of that array. Which is an unnecessary performance hit. Just use:

```
dem = ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

Or if its a single-band raster, simply:

```
dem = ds.ReadAsArray()
```

Regading the statistics, are you sure ArcMap shows the absolute high/low value? I know QGIS for example often draws the statistics from a sample of the dataset (for performance) and depending on the settings sometimes uses a percentile (eg 1%, 99%).

edit: BTW, is this a public dataset? Like an SRTM tile? It might help if you list the source.